# Can humans feel electricity without muscle's reacting to electricity?

Tags: electromagnetic

I've talked to people and seen stories that believe electricity can be felt as a vibration or some other way by touching something that is electrified. I don't have any questions about electromagnetic hypersensitivity [aka better call Saul](https://www.theguardian.com/science/shortcuts/2015/feb/15/better-call-saul-electromagnetic-hypersensitivity-real-health-risk) , or any questions about feeling the muscle spasms from electric or static shocks.

A specific example I can think of is someone touching the steel support beam of an industrial machine and saying they can feel the leakage current, can people feel electricity without feeling the muscle spasms associated with the shock?

For example if you applied an electric signal to your hand that was large enough for you to feel, then you took a drug that prevented your muscles from contracting and then applied the same signal, would you still feel it?

[I asked this at skeptics.se before](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37990/can-humans-feel-electricity-without-muscles-reacting-to-electricity) but it's on hold for being unclear.

Comment: Well I don't think this is something for engineers to answer, but for doctors or biologists

Comment: Very small 60 Hz AC currents can be felt (much more easily than DC). I know an electrician who tests for live wall sockets with a carefully placed finger. He died from other causes. Much higher frequencies seem to be sensed as "heat" (try looking up diathermy).

Comment: Connect a 9V battery to your tongue. You'll feel/taste it, but your tongue probably won't spasm.

Comment: Muscles function from electrical pulse trains to activate electro-chemical muscles but levels and isolation from feeling or pain sensors are well isolated, but certainly acupuncture can activate muscles and you do feel it as it crosses both paths of muscular pulse trains and sensory nerves. whereas you are unlikely to feel external shocks from extreme stretching so it is not effectively reversible have crosstalk, but certainly one can feel leakage especially if modulated. If you have tried tinsel on an old TV tube with dust charged at 20kV you will know what I mean.

Comment: and a fresh 9V battery will definitely contract your tongue tip muscles.  very accurate battery charge meter....  I dont suggest -48 but back in the day when my modem wasn't working I did a quick check for line connected and took a change that no 200v ring voltage was coming. I was then able to transfer Gerber files for a PCB PO. circa mid 90's

Comment: At frequencies above 100kHz nerves don't react and muscles don't contract.  This is put to use extensively in electro-surgery.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami I was thinking that too but got too many false leads about spine and nerve damage when looking from a medical angle for feeling shocks.

Comment: Skin effect (maybe damp skin) could easily prevent the current from penetrating down to the nerves.  It is generally accepted that it is safe to touch up to 30 volts safely.  Electricians often observe the "left hand rule" - where the left hand is behind your back so there is no chance of a discharge going through your heart.

Comment: @SDsolar I remember being told about the 'hit me worth this wooden 2x4 if I start shaking' rule, never seen it performed in earnest though

Comment: That made me LOL, @Daniel.  I know exactly what you mean.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

ESD discharge of 1~10A from 10kV charged body and 1000pf moist finger with 10ps rise time and 1 to 10 Ohm arc resistance and 10~100ns pulse duration is too short to activate any muscles but can certain be felt after walking across a nylon carpet with neoprene shoes and touching a doorknob.   You are less like to feel it but see a bigger arc by holding a key because the current density is now dimished more than a 100-fold by increase in key contact area.

Case 2: If you are charged up on an insulated platform to 1 Million volts, and have excellent insulation as your hair is fully extended and then relaxes  in say 1 second when turned off., you may barely be able to feel 1uA the threshold of feeling for most people.

More likely you feel the motion of the hair on the back of your neck touching your skin.

This is also the sensation one gets when a major lightning cloud passes overhead or standing near a large transforming going under isolated insulation BDV tests with the hair on the back of your head with 50kV on transformer tank 5m away and stray ions flowing thru your hair while you are standing behind a steel grating cage and even the paint gets charged up.  Even electrically floating cables 30m away strapped to wall, I have seen heard arc every 10 seconds zap zap zap from this DC field.  Not so with an AC field. **everyone felt these effects** but no muscles were affected and touching the tank paint or cage only got a mild ESD discharge.  HiV DC insulation tests are so much fun, but not safe for newbies.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

The same reason the electricity can make your muscles contract, by triggering nerves in or near the muscles, it can activate sensory nerves as well.

If you have ever felt an electric shock on your fingers, you have experienced this. Your fingers do not have any muscles in them (other than the small muscle fibers that cause goose bumps), so any sensation experienced there is not due to muscle contraction.

Comment: With my finger tips I feel things like pressure heat and textures, maybe pin prick pain is in there too. Does the electricity sensation override these senses? Or is it something else?

Comment: @daniel Electric shock will activate any number of the different senses in your fingers. There is no special sensory organ for electricity in human hands.

Comment: That's why I'm skeptical of someone touching a steel beam and 'feeling' leakage current, does it feel like a cold bit of steel, does it feel like a vibration?  Because I can point out other sources of this beam vibrating like the spinning motor above it.

Comment: @daniel Additionally a much smaller amount of the current would pass through the person, who has high resistance at the contact points and internally. The vast majority of what would already be a small current would stay in the steel beam.

Answer (score -2):

Two-part answer here
(1) Consider water in the earth. Depending on the mineral content, those underground pools will conduct electricity.

Thus voltage gradients, due to magma?, will cause currents to flow in the underground streaks/veins of water.

Flowing electrons produce magnetic fields. The human brain does respond to (intense?) magnetic fields.

Will those ---hypothesized---subterranean magnetic fields, should they fluctuate, thus inducing more or inducing less voltage in conductors at the surface, be the cause of divining-sticks slightly twitching?

I've read of the need to hold divining-sticks very gingerly, delicately, so the variations can be felt.

OK we have some causality. Do the magnitudes of forces work out?

(2) Regarding directly feeling current flows? yes. Hold a finger near the neon-filled glass tubes of a beer sign. The 50,000 volts of the internal arc, occurring 120 times a second, is capacitively coupled through the glass to you.

Some bars use LONG neon-filled tubes as major luminance. Those long tubes create long-range Electric fields that induce displacement currents into all objects nearby. With lots of coupling into the "ground" or earth. You, holding a finger up near those long tubes, provide a return path, and you'll feel your skin tingling. The slightest touch brings on the tingling.

How much current? Suppose the limiting impedance is capacitance from your feet to "earth". C = Eo * E r* Area/Distance. Area = 0.1meter^2. Distance = 0.1meter.
C = 9e-12 *  10(Er) * 0.1 = 9pF

What current? Q = C * V. Take derivative: dQ/dT (= I) = C * dV/dT + V * dC/dT
We'll use I = C * dV/dT, with dT/dT = 50,000 volts peak * 377 radian/sec (60Hz) or dV/dT ~~ 20 Million volts/second.

I = C * dV/dT = 9pF * 20 Million v/s = 180 microAmps. Dangerous. If you directly and strongly contact the arc inside the neon tube. The ones I saw had plastic transparent guards, to keep fingers about 4" away. Still the tingling.

Comment: For 1. Divining stick's are magic so I don't want to ask questions about them, 2. What does this tingling feel like, heat? Fast muscle contractions?

Comment: My grandpa used to do what he called witchin' - He would take two sticks out and point them straight out.  But when they crossed in front of him then X marks the spot - he would drill, and sure enough, water for the cows.  He said it didn't matter if they were coat hangers or just sticks he picked up.  He never mentioned a sensation.

Comment: With neon lights, you can feel the 120 times per second that the voltage reaches a peak, whether positive or negative.  Tingling is one word, but it is also the source of the buzz you hear from them, so that should give you an idea of what it feels like from that.  Just above the lowest note from a guitar.  Here is a chart that shows the comparison:  http://www.liutaiomottola.com/formulae/freqtab.htm

Comment: What does the charge flowing from long neon-tube at 50KV, 4" away, feel like? reach over and lightly brush the hairs on your arm. That 4" distance is the life-saver.